# Why is NaN not a json-schema primitive type?

Tags: javascript, validation, types, primitive, jsonschema

In my [json-schema](http://json-schema.org) I have defined a property as

```
"units":"number"
```

Now, using JJV validator (a json-schema implimentation), I encounter in my data model a value that is NaN. I would like to do something like this `"units":["number","NaN"]` instead of doing a custom coercion function like this:

```
    env.addTypeCoercion('number', function(x){
                if( isNaN(x))
                {
                    return 0
                }
                return x;
            });
```

The [JSON schema primitive types](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor8) in version 4 seem not to include NaN. How could I devise a schema that allows me to express a property as a number or a NaN?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it resolves to a Number. That seems reason enough.

Comment: After the edit I don't see a reason to consider the question primarly opinion-base.

Comment: I've voted to reopen. This question has a simple technical answer which is the one given by Kevin Reid. No opinion needed.

Answer (score 4):

[The definition of JSON](http://json.org/) **does not allow NaN values**. Therefore any schema for JSON structures which permitted NaN would be permitting things that **are not JSON**.

If you create JSON using `JSON.stringify` that includes a NaN value, it will be replaced with `null`.

Comment: Ah, looking at JJV implementation, looks like they explicitly intended on not including NaN.  `'number': function (x) {
                // Use x === x instead of !isNaN(x) for speed
                return typeof (x === 'number' && x === x) 
            },` so I added `|| typeof isNaN(x);`

Comment: Indeed, JSON does not officially support NaN and Infinity tokens. One big weakness with JSON is that it does not fully support these values despite the fact that they are perfectly valid floating point values that occur all the time in real data. Python's JSON implementation, for good or bad, will emit these tokens by default, so even though it is not technically valid JSON, this does occur quite frequently.